# Adding multiple users to groups on multiple servers - powershell error

Tags: powershell

```
    # Define the list of servers
$servers = "SERVER1", "SERVER2"

# Define the users to add to the Remote Desktop Users group
$usersToAdd = "smithj", "doej"

# Loop through each server
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Write-Host "Adding users to Remote Desktop Users group on $server"
    
    # Loop through each user and add them to the group
    foreach ($user in $usersToAdd) {
        $userPrincipal = [ADSI]"WinNT://$server/$user,user"
        $group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$server/Remote Desktop Users,group"
        
        # Check if the user and group exist, then add the user to the group
        if ($userPrincipal -ne $null -and $group -ne $null) {
            $group.Add($userPrincipal.Path)
            Write-Host "Added $user to Remote Desktop Users group on $server"
        } else {
            Write-Host "User $user or Remote Desktop Users group not found on $server"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error on the $group.Add($usePrincipal.Path portion;

```
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "An invalid directory pathname was passed
"
At line:18 char:13
+             $group.Add($userPrincipal.Path)
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI
```

Any idea why it wouldn't find the pathname?

An issue with $group.Add? or a problem with my $userPrincipal variable?

Does .path not work with $userPrincipal = [ADSI]"WinNT://$server/$user,user" ?

Comment: Does this help https://serverfault.com/questions/765295/cannot-add-users-to-local-group-via-powershell